# Bash variable in for loop

Tags: bash

I am sure this has been answered before, but I cannot find the solution.

```
for i in `ls | grep ^t`; do echo $i; done
```

This gives me the expected results (the files and directories starting with t). 
If I want to use a shell variable in the for loop (with the pipe), how do I do this? 
This was my start but it does not work.

```
z="ls | grep ^t"
for i in `$z` ; do echo $i; done
```

EDIT: I agree this example was not wisely chosen, but what I basically need ishow to use a variable (here `$z`) in the for loop (`for i in $z`) which has at least one pipe.

I try to state my question more clearly: How do I need to define my variable (if I want to loop over the output of a command with one or more pipes) and how is the call for the for loop?

Comment: you should write `z=\`ls | grep ^t\``

Comment: @PatrickTrentin It's syntactically correct, but you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @chepner fair enough; eta: never-mind, I looked it on my own. (:

Comment: @chepner I answered `z=\`ls | grep ^t\`
for i in "$z"; do echo $i; done` and `z="$(ls | grep ^t)"; for i in "$z"; do echo $i; done` and I got `-3` do you know why? Please give me some advice.

Comment: @terces907 Because [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is bad.

Comment: Hey, thanks, sometimes I just think people should leave some messages before they press downvote. In my case I would get three advices. In this way I would be appreciated event it's `-3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To loop through all files starting with `t`, you should use `glob` expansion instead of parsing `ls` output:

```
$ ls t*
tf  tfile
$ ls
abcd  tf  tfile
$ for i in t*; do echo "$i"; done
tf
tfile
$
```

Your approach will break in a number of cases, the simplest being when file names contain spaces. There is no need to use any external tool here; t* expands to all files starting with t.

As for your question, you use `ls | grep ^t`

And another good practice is to use subshell instead of backticks which are more readable and can be nested, use this: `$(ls | grep ^t)`

Comment: I only read the first part of your answer, which was why I posted my own. Your advice to use `t*` is the best idea - you should move that to the top of your answer then I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a variable for this. You don't put commands in strings. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion about why.

You shouldn't be using a `for` loop to read data line-by-line anyway. See [Bash FAR 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for better ways to do that.

Specifically (though really read that page):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(some command)
```